# call java function from c++ (jni) isn't working at all

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i've found a lot of posts online but non of them seem to have helped me to get it right..

My problem is i want to call a android java function from the ndk c++ part..

when i get the class with:

```
jclass icls = jenv->GetObjectClass(obj);
```

i get this error:
*E/AndroidRuntime(27397): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setValues' signature='()V' in class Ljava/lang/Class;*
=> jmid == 0

when i call it like below with **"FindClass"** i get this error: *A/libc(26692): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 26743 (Thread-8302)*

the findclass and method seems to work (!= 0) so could there be a problem with ***obj***?

Anyone? Thx in Advance..

JAVA - Main Class:

```
package com.new.test;
class Test{
   public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        run();
   }

   run(){
         int x = 10;
         new DoStuff(x);
   }
   public void setValues(){     
       Log.e("","SET VALUES");
   }
}
```

JAVA 2 JNI:

```
public class DoStuff{   
    public DoStuff(int x){
        nativeDoStuff(x);
    }

    private static native long nativeDoStuff(int x);

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("do_stuff");
    }
}
```

C++: cpp

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_new_test_DoStuff_nativeDoStuff (JNIEnv * jenv, jobject obj, jint x){

    jclass icls = jenv->FindClass("com/new/test/Test");
    //jclass icls = jenv->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID jmid = jenv->GetMethodID(icls, "setValues","()V");
    jenv->CallVoidMethod(obj,jmid);

}
```

C++: h

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_new_test_DoStuff_nativeDoStuff (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Test.setValues()` is an instance method - it needs a valid `Test` object to be executed. Meanwhile, the method `nativeDoStuff` doesn't have one. It's a static method, all it has (as a second parameter) is a class object of class DoStuff. You're erroneously passing that class pointer as a `this` pointer to `CallVoidMethod()` - that's fatally wrong.

Move everything into just one class (either `Test` or `DoStuff`, it does not matter) and declare `nativeDoStuff()` as nonstatic on the Java side. Or make `doStuff()` itself static and use `jenv->CallStaticVoidMethod()` as the last line.

Comment: oh THX a lot! never thought about that, cause it worked before (of course cause i had no use for the obj)..

i moved everything to Test and removed the static from nativeDoStuff().. does this have any disadvanteges? i used made it static cause it was like this in opencv.

Comment: Static methods have marginally less call overhead (no `this` to pass around). But at some point you might need `this` to call back into Java. Your call.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this properly, "obj" in this case is going to point to the DoStuff object, not the Test object. So you're trying to call your setValues method on an object which does not contain this method. You should either make your native method be a member of Test or pass the instance of Test into the function.

Comment: ok ic.. but i also tried to put the "setValues" function in the "DoStuff" class and it didn't work out.. shouldn't that be right then? or could you give me a example how to pass the instance?

Comment: i have put setValues again in DoStuff and get this error:
*"E/dalvikvm(31575): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference 0x341c3722 (index 3528 in a table of size 139)
E/dalvikvm(31575): VM aborting
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 31636 (Thread-8398)"*

Comment: i added (and changed all obj to javaObj): jobject javaObj = jenv->NewGlobalRef(obj); but i doesn't seem to do the trick
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 31636 (Thread-8398)"*

Comment: ok sry for spamming :) but i also tried to include the DoStuff in the Test Class and it seems to get a little bit futher.. now i got this error *03-25 20:54:43.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2682): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8470
03-25 20:54:43.280: E/AndroidRuntime(2682): java.lang.AbstractMethodError* but it seems that it doesn't gets to the setValues class (its not logging anything)

Comment: THX for your help.. Seva and you were right, it was the static problem or what you mentioned the wrong obj. i passed a instance of Test to DoStuff and from there to the nativeDoStuff and used it for the Call.. Worked like a charm, i just didn't got to do it right yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the void in:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com ...
```

to **jlong**.

Comment: thx, but i'm not returning anything (i would say).. The answer of Seva seems to work for now.